# Agregar extensiones sqlsrv. dll en CPANEL (conexión a BD SQLSERVER)

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, cpanel

Hola buenas tardes subí un sistema web al CPanel.
En el desarrollo utilice SQL Server ODBC Driver y los archivos .dll (extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll, extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll) que coloque en la carpeta ext, también los agregue agregue en el archivo .ini de PHP todo esto con la finalidad de poder crear conexión con una base de datos de SQL server, pero cuando subí mi proyecto a CPanel me marca el siguiente error ***Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()*** y me imagino que es porque espera que configure también las extensiones que ocupe en el desarrollo de manera local y es ese mi problema.

> Opciones en CPANEL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y bonita tarde.

Comment: Va a depender de las opciones del servidor donde se aloja el sitio: puedes ajustar los moodulos/extensiones de PHP en CPanel? esta disponible sql server para ser activado? Y finalmente, puedes conectarte al sevidor sql server desde dicho servidor web?

Comment: @F.Igor y como es que puedo activar esa opción? como se que si puedo activar ese driver en el CPANEL?

Comment: .dll son librerías para Windows. CPanel es en Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se puede dependiendo de la configuracion del servidor (si permite versiones de PHP y extensiones/configuraciones adicionales):

Debe existir un panel como este a continuacion, para seleccionar la version de PHP (o directamente extensiones de PHP)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego una ventana de seleccion similar a esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la lista de extensiones disponibles debe estar `pdo_sqlsrv`

Si el servidor no esta basado en windows es mas dificil que venga esta extension activada, ya que no viene por defecto en la instalacion de PHP y necesita ser compilada para ser activada.

Si la extension no esta disponible y tienes acceso al servidor linux, pueden seguir las instrucciones entregadas por Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: No me sale esa opción. Anexo una captura de pantalla con las opciones que me sales.

Comment: Me apoyas a configurar mi servidor por favor?